# Is there a way to make Google Sheet files as static data values or export to cloud databases?

Tags: google-sheets

When making a master sheet that sums some values across hundreds of Google Sheets with the functions importrange, or query data across hundreds of Google Sheets' IDs, it takes longer time to load...

Is there a way to have a buffer like database in Google that is continuously updating the master sheet so whenever I open it the data has already been updated instead of waiting to execute the functions? In other basic words, as if the master sheet file is continuously open in my desktop. So whenever I need to look at it, it is already open and the `importrange` function has finished doing the job. That will make the dynamic data calculation & synchronization much faster specially if you need to look for multiple filtered values and data.
Probably working with cloud database and keeping the sheets that have `importrange` data and calculations in the database will solve the issue.

**Note:**
I found sites to work as linking a trigger of Google Sheet with another application but don't really solve my issues like https://integromat.com/ or https://zapier.com. I found similar question where something called SQL works as a cloud database for Google but I'm very primitive to it so far.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I found sites to work as linking a trigger of google sheet with another application but don't really solve my issues like <https://www.integromat.com/en/login?go=%2Forg%2F751505> or <zapier.com>. I found similar question where something called SQL works as a cloud database for google but I'm very primitive to it so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the master sheet that makes the calculation as a separate sheet. And I made a new sheet that just importrange the results of the calculation instead. so it run faster in this way.